# PHP try catch not catching PDOException/Exception

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

I have some PDO insert code inside **try catch** block. I am deliberately passing wrong values to the execute function so that the insert will fail. i.e.;
inserting duplicate values on a column that is declared as primary. As tested the insert query fails while executing on console, giving error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

However, my try--catch block is not catching this exception. Is it because PHP does not throw an exception for duplicate entry? I am new to PHP. Have been searching the net but cannot seem to find a clue:

```
try
 {  
     $query = $conn->prepare($preSQL);
     $query->execute($postSQL);  //$postSQL is the associative array for placeholders
     $dataAdded = $query->rowCount();
     $lastInsertId = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
 }
catch(PDOException $e)
 {
    fwrite($myfile,PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($myfile,$e->getMessage());
    fclose($myfile);
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: check here : https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors

Answer (score 2):

You might need to include the PDOException eg

```
use PDO;
use PDOException;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Step:

Add this code to top of the page:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
```

> use error_reporting(E_ALL) only in development mode!

2. Step

Add the code below after your $conn = new PDO(...);

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: then it means : its not throwing a fatal error  and ur error_handling level is too low. Let me fix it for you

Comment: Done. Still the exception is escaping the catch block. Actually my php.ini was already configured to report errors. Below are the values from php.ini: </ br>error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT </ br> display_errors=On </ br> display_startup_errors=On